# Where did the AdvanceKeyBase folder in /Users/Shared come from?

Tags: permission, file, root

Where did the AdvanceKeyBase folder in /Users/Shared come from ?

Its owned by root with group wheel there's also a hidden folder called Key-Base with the same permissions / ownership.

It's a recent addition and since it seems related to encryption I'd love to know how the hell it got there ?

Thx

Comment: What have you installed recently?

Comment: did you ever find out? i have the same now